# React Class Inheritance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having problem with a component inheriting information from a previous component in React JS. In the example below I'm trying to get information from the logged in user that are in props. However, I'm not able to load this information when the dashboard page is assembled (ComponentDidMount).

componente/BaseDashboard.js

```
import React from 'react'; import Header from
'../../components/Header';

import { connect } from 'react-redux'; import * as actions from
'../../store/actions'; import Footer from '../../components/Footer';

class BaseDashboard extends React.Component {
    state = {
        statusMenu: true
    }

    alertMenu() {
        this.setState({ statusMenu: !this.state.statusMenu })
    }

    alertMenu = this.alertMenu.bind(this);

    render() {
        
        return (
            <>
                <div className="wrapper">

                    <Header handleLogout={this.props.handleLogout} userData={this.props} alertMenu={this.alertMenu} />
                    <div className="content-wrapper">
                        {this.props.children}
                    </div>


                    <Footer handleLogout={this.props.handleLogout} userData={this.props} alertMenu={this.alertMenu} />
                </div>
            </>
        );
    } }

export default connect(null, actions)(BaseDashboard);
```

componente/index.js

```
import React from 'react'; import BaseDashboard from
'./BaseDashboard'; import { connect } from 'react-redux'; import * as
actions from '../../store/actions';

const baseDashboard = Component => {
    class ComponentBaseDashboard extends React.Component {


        componentDidMount() {
            const { authorized, getViewUser, history } = this.props;
            getViewUser();

            if (!authorized) {
                return history.replace("/");
            }
        }

        componentDidUpdate(nextProps) {
            const { authorized, history } = this.props;
            if (!nextProps.authorized || !authorized) {
                return history.replace("/");
            }
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <BaseDashboard>
                    <Component {...this.props} />
                </BaseDashboard>
            );
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        authorized: state.auth.authorized,
        user: state.auth.user
    });

    return connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(ComponentBaseDashboard); }

export default baseDashboard;
```

In this method the message "TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined" is occurring when I run console.log for this.props.user
pages/Dashboard.js

```
componentDidMount() {
   const { user } = this.props;
   console.log(this.props);
   this.setState({ user: user })
}
```

The dashboard page I'm calling this way in my routes

Comment: Just a side note, class-based components and Redux with lifecycle methods (rather than hooks) looks a bit old-fashioned these days.

Comment: You need to return the class you're declaring. Otherwise it's just a local declaration that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You say `this.props` is undefined in an unknown component (you posted 2 but none log this.props).

Here is a [minimum example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example without all the irrelevant code that show your code should work:

```js
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;

const initialState = { value: 22 };
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  return state;
};

class BaseDashboard extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(
      'base props no problem:',
      Boolean(this.props)
    );
  }
  render() {
    return <div>hello world</div>;
  }
}
const ConnectedBaseDashboard = connect()(BaseDashboard);
const baseDashboard = (Component) => {
  class ComponentBaseDashboard extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      console.log('props no problem:', this.props);
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <BaseDashboard>
          <Component {...this.props} />
        </BaseDashboard>
      );
    }
  }
  const mapStateToProps = (state) => state;
  return connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {}
  )(ComponentBaseDashboard);
};

//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(
      () => (next) => (action) => next(action)
    )
  )
);
const App = baseDashboard(ConnectedBaseDashboard);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Maybe you can use the above snippet to demonstrate the problem you are experiencing in your question.